# If $x + y + z = 1$, what is $\min(xyz)$ where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positive numbers?

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, schur-inequality

$x,y,z$ are positive numbers and given $x + y + z = 1$. I was initially required to prove that $xy+yz+xz - 3xyz \leq \frac{1}{4}$. I then manipulated such that I was required to prove that $xyz \geq \frac{1}{36}$ (using $x^3 +y^3 +z^2 -3xyz = (x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^-xy-yz-xz)$ I know how to prove that the upper limit of $xyz$ is $\frac{1}{27}$, but I am not too sure how to find the lower limit of $xyz$. Any help would be appreciated, and if you have any other suggestions on how to solve the original inequality - that would be appreciated as well. Apologies if I am not correctly following any of the posting guidelines as this is my first question.

Comment: This could be worked with Lagrange multipliers.  Have you taken a Calculus sequence?

Comment: What happens when $x$, $y$ or $z$ tends to zero?

Comment: There is no minimum. The infimum is $0$. Say $x=y=0.01$, and $z=0.98$. Then $xyz=0.98\cdot 10^{-4}$. And I can get any lower number that I want, as long as it is greater than $0$.

Answer (score 3):

As it was already pointed out, there is no minimum. Since $x,y,z>0$, we have that $xyz > 0$. But if you fix any $0 < \varepsilon < \frac 14$ and consider the point $(\sqrt\varepsilon, \sqrt\varepsilon, 1-2\sqrt\varepsilon)$, you see that the objective function value is given by
$$
\sqrt \varepsilon \sqrt \varepsilon (1-2\sqrt \varepsilon) = \varepsilon (1-2 \sqrt \varepsilon),
$$

which is bounded by $\varepsilon$. So, you can find points $(x,y,z)$ in the admissible region such that $xyz < \varepsilon < \frac 14$. Since $xyz>0$, we conclude that $0$ is the infimum but not the minimum.

Comment: (+1) But could we write like this?" But if you fix any $0<\epsilon<\frac 14$ and consider..."

Comment: @lonestudent You are right, it is way cleaner, I'll make the changes.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality, which you "was initially required to prove", we can prove by the following way.

We need to prove that:
$$xy+xz+yz-3xyz\leq\frac{1}{4}$$ or
$$(x+y+z)^3\geq4(x+y+z)(xy+xz+yz)-12xyz$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^3+3x^2y+3x^2z+2xyz)\geq\sum_{cyc}(4x^2y+4x^2z)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^3-x^2y-x^2z+2xyz)\geq0,$$ which is true because by Schur$$\sum_{cyc}(x^3-x^2y-x^2z+xyz)\geq0$$ and $$\sum_{cyc}xyz\geq0.$$

Answer (score 1):

I think $\min(xyz)$ is $0$, when any of x,y,z is reaching $0$.

Comment: Sorry x,y,z are positive numbers, so I think that should exclude any of them being 0

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Sure, but you can make $x=y$ arbitrarily small, then $z=1-2x\approx 1$. Then the product is about (slightly less than) $x^2$. So there is no minimum, but the infimum is $0$.